# Elasticsearch-Py Bulk Helper expected field [create], [delete], [index] or [update] but found [_op_type]'

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm currently trying to bulk index a bunch of documents to a data stream in elastic using Python and I'm getting strange errors.

Here is my code:

```
for event in raw:
            tmp = { 
                    "@timestamp": event['timestamp'],
                    "event" : {"kwh": event['kwh']},
                    "location": f"{self.args.location}",
                    "sourcetype": "meterdata",
                    "host.name": f"{self.args.name}"
            }
            payload={   
                        "_op_type": "create",
                        "_index": "energiemonitoring",
                        "_source": tmp
                    }
            payloadlist.append(payload.copy())
        payload=json.loads(json.dumps(payloadlist,default=self.make_json_serial))

        r = helpers.bulk(
            self.es_client,
            payload,
            raise_on_error=False
        )
```

Which is following the documentation provided by Elastic [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/client-helpers.html#bulk-helpers).

Sadly I get the following error:

```
elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected field [create], [delete], [index] or [update] but found [_op_type]'
```

Replacing the _op_type with create is not helping either:
Code:

```
payload={   
          "create": tmp,
          "_index": "energiemonitoring",
}
```

Error:

```
elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [@timestamp]'
```

My Elastic version is 8.5.3

Has someone experienced a similar issue before?

Thank in advance!

Comment: what is the verson of the elastic python client ?

Comment: What is the thing you are trying to do with `payloadlist.append(payload.copy())` and
`payload=json.loads(json.dumps(payloadlist,default=self.make_json_serial))`?
I am guessing that this is the place it messes up.

Comment: seemed to fix the issue. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialization messed up the request. Thanks again for the help